# Big O and small o notation numerical

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics

I am confused regarding the numerical of Big O and small o notation. This topic is related to numerical methods.
[image]

It would be great if someone can help me with this.
This question is from the book -

> Numerical Analysis: Mathematics of Scientific Computing
> By Kincaid and Cheney, 3rd edition Brooks/Cole, 2002

**Edit**
Please review my solution? Is this correct?
[image]

Comment: What does "the numerical of big O notation" mean? Can you be specific about what you're confused by?

Comment: Thank you @MishaLavrov for your reply. I have to answer whether this statement is correct or not?

Comment: Yes, that's what the question is asking for.

Comment: Thank you @MishaLavrov. It would be great if you can help me solving this numerical correctly.

Comment: That's why I'm trying to ask what you're confused by. What have you tried to answer this question? What sort of things have you learned about this topic? Try to provide context instead of just a question statement.

Comment: Thank you @MishaLavrov. I have edited the question. Please review. Is my solution correct? What I have learned is that if the ratio( as shown) comes as 0, then it is small o notation. Just taking a mathematics class after a long time. Still little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can solve this problem by taking the limit
$$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1/n}{(n+1)/n^2}.
$$
It's more standard to take the reciprocal limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)/n^2}{1/n}$. In that case, the rule is that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$, then $f(n) = o(g(n))$; if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ is any constant *including $0$*, then $f(n) = O(g(n))$.

But the limit of $\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}$ is the reciprocal of the limit of $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$. So in your case, because you computed $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1/n}{(n+1)/n^2} = 1$, you know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)/n^2}{1/n} = 1$ as well. This tells you that

- $(n+1)/n^2 = O(1/n)$ would be a true statement, if you were asked about that.
- $(n+1)/n^2 = o(1/n)$ is false, because the limit is not $0$.

---

Over time, you should be able to solve such problems more by "intuition". If you split apart $(n+1)/n^2$ into $1/n + 1/n^2$, you see that it's equal to $1/n$ plus a "lower-order term": the function $1/n^2$ goes to $0$ more quickly than $1/n$ as $n \to \infty$. That is enough to know that $(n+1)/n^2 = O(1/n)$. Just $1/n^2$ by itself would be $o(1/n)$, but $(n+1)/n^2$ is not, because it also has a term that's going to $0$ just as quickly as $1/n$.

Comment: Thank you @MishaLavrov for correcting me and explaining me the concept so precisely.